# How to combine multiple models into one using linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have a SecurityLog Model returning rows from a sql database.  I also have a SecurityLogOfficer and Officer table which contains many-many relationship.

**How can I merge models together and display a concatenated list of officer names?**

```
IQueryable<SecurityLog> sort = from s in _context.SecurityLog                                      
                                  .Include(f => f.SecurityLogOfficers)
                                  .ThenInclude(e => e.Officer)
                                  //.Select(x => new PageViewModel
                                  //{ OfficersNames = string.Join(",", x.SecurityLogOfficers.Select(o => o.Officer.FullName)) })
                         select s;
```

**Essentially I would like to take my list of SecurityLogOfficers and display list of officer names on one row (comma separated)**

[image]

**Update 02/11/20**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SecurityLog)
{
    <tr>
        <td style="width:4% !important">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
        </td>
        <td style="width:5% !important">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventDate)
        </td>


        <td style="width:5% !important">
            @Model.OfficerNames[i]
}
```

**Index Page Model**

```
public class PageViewModel
{            
    public List<string> OfficerNames { get; internal set; }
}
```

This gives explicit conversion error....

```
IQueryable<SecurityLog> sort = from s in _context.SecurityLog
                                        .Include(a => a.Entity)
                                        .Include(b => b.EventType)
                                        .Include(c => c.Location)
                                        .Include(d => d.ShiftRange)
                                        .Include(f => f.SecurityLogOfficers)
                                        .ThenInclude(e => e.Officer)
                                        .Select(x => new PageViewModel
                                        { OfficerNames = string.Join(",", x.SecurityLogOfficers.Select(o => o.Officer.FullName)) })
                                       select s;

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            sort = sort.Where(s => s.Narrative.Contains(searchString)                
                                || s.SubjectFirst.Contains(searchString)
                                || s.SubjectLast.Contains(searchString)
                                || s.OfficerNames.Contains(searchString));


        }

SecurityLog = await PaginatedList<SecurityLog>.CreateAsync(sort
            .Include(a => a.Entity)
            .Include(b => b.EventType)
            .Include(c => c.Location)
            .Include(d => d.ShiftRange)
            .Include(e => e.Officer)
            .Include(f => f.SecurityLogOfficers)
            .AsNoTracking(), pageIndex ?? 1, pageSize);
```

Comment: you can use Anonymous type : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types

Comment: You could just show the `OfficersNames` with ViewModel with your commented line.But could not show the `SecurityLogOfficers` with `Officer` which is shown list of officer names.Because it is a model.

Comment: @Rena - How can I display OfficerNames on my index razor page?  My code currently loops through the SecurityLog Model, not the index model. 

 /@foreach (var item in Model.SecurityLog)
        {@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID) }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working demo you could refer to:

1.Model:

```
public class SecurityLog
{
    public int SecurityLogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<SecurityLogOfficers> SecurityLogOfficers { get; set; }
}
public class Officer
{
    public int OfficerId { get; set; }
    public string Active { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public IList<SecurityLogOfficers> SecurityLogOfficers { get; set; }
}
public class SecurityLogOfficers
{
    public int OfficerId { get; set; }
    public Officer Officer { get; set; }
    public int SecurityLogId { get; set; }
    public SecurityLog SecurityLog { get; set; }
}
```

2.Index.cshtml:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SecurityLog[0].Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SecurityLog[0].SecurityLogOfficers[0].Officer.FullName)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.SecurityLog) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @(string.Join(",", item.SecurityLogOfficers.Select(u=>u.Officer.FullName)))              
                </td>           
            </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

3.Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public IList<SecurityLog> SecurityLog { get;set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    IQueryable<SecurityLog> sort = from s in _context.SecurityLog
                                .Include(f => f.SecurityLogOfficers)
                                .ThenInclude(e => e.Officer)
                                    select s;
    SecurityLog = await sort.ToListAsync();
}
```

4.Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you!  This works perfectly!  One last thing...How can I filter sort to search for these names?...if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                sort = sort.Where(s => s.Narrative.Contains(searchString)                                    
                                    || s.ContactName.Contains(searchString)                                    
                                    || s.SecurityLogOfficers.Select(u => u.Officer.FullName).Contains(searchString));
            } ...........returns "Sequence contains more than one element"

Answer (score 1):

You should use a display property the will do the concatenation or make the concatenation when mapping your db entity to your ViewModel (as commented line in your example). Given that it's probably for display purpose only, you shouldn't bring that logic at db level imo.

Comment: Boisevert - Thank you for your response.  I tried creating a list of concatenated officers in a class within the page model and on my razor page I can get it to display by using @Model.OfficerNames[i] but since this is outside of my securitylog model (@foreach (var item in Model.SecurityLog){} my searching does not work when searching for both an officer name inside the officer concat field and free text within securitylog.  So ideally I would like for the officername list to be a part of the SecurityLog record, since that is what search is looking at. Any ideas?